# [GAPI][Javascript]Signing-in parameter "login_hint" using gapi behaving differently on Safari and Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-oauth

I am seeing a small difference in behaviour when using this piece of code on Safari and Chrome.

```
window.gapi.load('auth2', () => {
      window.gapi.auth2
        .init({
          client_id: getConfig('google').clientId,
          ux_mode: 'popup',
          scope: 'profile email openid',
          login_hint: getLoggedInUserEmail(),
          redirect_uri: `${window.location.origin}/${redirect_url}`,
        })
        .then(() => {
          const GoogleAuth = window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
            GoogleAuth.signIn().then(() => {
              resolve(GoogleAuth.currentUser.get().getAuthResponse().id_token);
            });
        });
    });
```

On Chrome : The authorization directly happens, i.e. the google popup opens, and closes after authorization without any user intervention. To be more specific - the url in the popup is
(https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?login_hint=getLoggedInUserEmail&openid.realm&scope=email+profile+openid&response_type=permission+id_token&redirect_uri=redirect_uri)

On Safari : The choose profile opens in the popup. This leads to user needing to select the account.
To be more specific - the url in the popup is (https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth/oauthchooseaccount?login_hint=getLoggedInUserEmail&openid.realm&scope=email+profile+openid&response_type=permission+id_token&redirect_uri=redirect_uri)

Notice that, on chrome, sign-in flow redirects directly to `/oauth2/auth` and on safari, it redirects to `/oauth2/auth/oauthchooseaccount`.

I am already logged in to google in my browser using the email I am sending into login_hint while signing in using gapi.

My questions are -

1. Why is there this discrepancy?
2. Can Safari behave like Chrome?

Comment: So are you only concerned about the behavior if someone is currently logged into their Google account on the browser? The problem is that if someone is using multiple Google accounts on a browser then the browser should SHOULD ask them which account they want to use for login and not assume one account over the other.

Comment: I get your point. But in my setup, I only had one account logged into google. Still there is a discrepancy, where in Safari, the user has to choose the account again, whereas in chrome, authorization happens by itself.